# C++ - Ray Casting in with DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx, raycasting

I'm having lots of troubles with my ray casting calculations and can't quite figure out where the problem is. I'm using DirectX's Math library to create vectors and the such.

Here is my code so far:

```
auto normalizedDeviceCoords = glm::vec2((float(a_frontend->GetMousePos().x) / float(a_frontend->GetWidth())) * 2.f - 1.f, 
                                        -((float(a_frontend->GetMousePos().y) / float(a_frontend->GetHeight())) * 2.f - 1.f));
auto mouseOrigin = DirectX::XMVectorSet(normalizedDeviceCoords.x, normalizedDeviceCoords.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
auto mouseEnd = DirectX::XMVectorSet(normalizedDeviceCoords.x, normalizedDeviceCoords.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);

auto viewproj = DirectX::XMMatrixMultiply(a_frontend->GetViewMatrix(), a_frontend->GetProjMatrix());
auto determinant = DirectX::XMMatrixDeterminant(a_camera.ViewProj());
auto inverseviewproj = DirectX::XMMatrixInverse(&determinant, a_camera.ViewProj());
auto rayOrigin = DirectX::XMVector4Transform(mouseOrigin, inverseviewproj);
auto rayEnd = DirectX::XMVector4Transform(mouseEnd, inverseviewproj);
auto raySubtraction = DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(rayEnd, rayOrigin);
auto rayDirection = DirectX::XMVector3Normalize(raySubtraction);

auto planeNormal = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
auto pointOnPlane = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.f, -0.1f, 0.f, 0.f);

DirectX::XMFLOAT3 denominator;
DirectX::XMStoreFloat3(&denominator, DirectX::XMVector3Dot(planeNormal, rayDirection));
if (fabs(denominator.x) <= 0.0001f)
{
    return;
}

auto pointMinusRay = DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(pointOnPlane, rayOrigin);

DirectX::XMFLOAT3 t;
auto almostT = DirectX::XMVector3Dot(pointMinusRay, planeNormal);
DirectX::XMStoreFloat3(&t, DirectX::XMVectorScale(almostT, 1.f / denominator.x));

if (t.x < 0)
{
    return;
}

auto rayDirectionLength = DirectX::XMVector3Length(rayDirection);
auto rayPoint = DirectX::XMVectorAdd(rayOrigin, DirectX::XMVectorScale(rayDirection, t.x));
```

I have checked that the normalized device coordinates are correct, the ray direction's length is also one, and the ray direction appears to be correct (hard to tell by just the numbers).

Any info will be useful. I've already looked at some information here on stack overflow and on other forums also and haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the ray point that is on the plane is correct only on the y-axis (it is -0.1 which is correct). The x and z positions are incorrect, when it should be 5, but it's 0.1.

Comment: Have you tried the ``DirectXCollision.h`` functions for these tests? Also, consider ``using namespace DirectX;`` in your ``.cpp`` file.

Comment: I shall check out that header, see if there aren't any useful functions there, thanks Chuck. And I would however I'm following a previous programmers coding style, trying to make the code fluent.

Comment: Could the problem be that `mouseOrigin` should be a fixed point, and not slide around, a fixed offset from `mouseEnd`?  Because the way it looks now,  `raySubtraction` just ends up being a constant vector, no matter where the mouse goes, so `rayDirection` never changes.  Nobody smarter seems to be answering, so I'm just throwing my guess out there.

Comment: That could be, I noticed the same thing happening with rayDirection being constant no matter if the mouse moved. I'll check that out and see what happens, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team mate was able to solve this problem. He just started using the DirectX Math function Vector3Unproject. This will take the mouse coordinates and turn them into world coordinates, using both the origin and the end (so taking the mouse coordinates with a z of 0 and then of 1). Then subtracting those from one another to get a vector that points somewhere in the world. We were then able to take that direction and transform it according to the camera's current y position divided by the negative of the direction vector's y. Here is all the code that we have now:

```
DirectX::XMVECTOR mouseNear = DirectX::XMVectorSet((float)a_mousePos.x, (float)a_mousePos.y, 0.0f, 0.0f);
DirectX::XMVECTOR mouseFar = DirectX::XMVectorSet((float)a_mousePos.x, (float)a_mousePos.y, 1.0f, 0.0f);
DirectX::XMVECTOR unprojectedNear = DirectX::XMVector3Unproject(mouseNear, 0, 0, a_width, a_height, a_nearZ, a_farZ,
                                                                a_projection, a_view, DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity());
DirectX::XMVECTOR unprojectedFar = DirectX::XMVector3Unproject(mouseFar, 0, 0, a_width, a_height, a_nearZ, a_farZ,
                                                                a_projection, a_view, DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity());
DirectX::XMVECTOR result = DirectX::XMVector3Normalize(DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(unprojectedFar, unprojectedNear));
DirectX::XMFLOAT3 direction;
DirectX::XMStoreFloat3(&direction, result);
return direction;

//Get the distance to the ground.
DirectX::XMFLOAT3 cameraPosition = a_camera.GetPosition();

//Get the point on the ground.
cameraPosition.x += direction.x * (cameraPosition.y / -direction.y);
cameraPosition.z += direction.z * (cameraPosition.y / -direction.y);
```

Hopefully this may prove helpful for someone in the future.